# OpenCV how to Group Rectangles

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I would like some help explaining how to use the opencv group rectangles function in python [SHOWN HERE](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=rejectlevels#grouprectangles).

I am running 2 haar cascades to detect objects in the image, but now I would like to merge the rectangles together.  I am guessing thats what the groupRectangles is used for.

```
cv2.groupRectangles(rectList, groupThreshold, eps, weights, levelWeights)
```

I am assuming that rectList is the vector returned by cv2.cascade.detectMultiScale()?
Also I am not sure what the weights, and levelWeights are or what tehy are used for and would appreciate it if anyone could explain that, or show me where I can find out about it as i cant 
find it in the documentation.

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: You should more clearly define what you mean by grouping rectangles, or am I missing some opencv-terminology here?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something changed in the meantime, but following the link you provided the definition is:

```
cv2.groupRectangles(rectList, groupThreshold[, eps]) → rectList, weights
```

So yes, `rectList` is a list of rectangles, in your case you would use the one returned by `cv2.cascade.detectMultiScale()`. While the optional `eps` controls, how similar (in terms of position and size) two rectangles need to be to be merged, the `groupThreshold` indicates how many rectangles at least need to be merged into one in order the keep the merged one.

You will be returned the new list of rectangles and a weight for every rectangle, I assume the weight reflects how many rectangles where merged and how similar they were.